# Uno card draw game cant print the card to the panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im working on a program that draws a card from a collection(deck) of uno cards. It should display the first card on startup, then every time the "next card" button is pressed it draws another card. However I'm very new to GUI's and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I get "Uno" in the box that should display the text representation of the card.

```
package Uno;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{
private PlayingCardPanel panel;
    private JPanel field;
    private JPanel menu;

public GameFrame(){
       this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       this.setSize( 300, 150);
       this.setTitle("UNO");
       this.createFieldPanel();
       this.createMenuPanel();
       this.add(field);
       this.add(menu);
   }

    private void createMenuPanel(){
      menu = new JPanel();
      menu.setBounds(0,300,250,100);


      JButton drawButton = new JButton("Next Card");
      drawButton.setSize(300,200);
      drawButton.addActionListener(new drawListener());

      menu.add(drawButton);
    }

    private void createFieldPanel()
    {
        field = new JPanel();
        field.setBounds(0,0,250,200);
        panel = new PlayingCardPanel();
        field.add(panel);
    }

   private class drawListener implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           panel.drawCard();
       }
   }
}

    package Uno;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PlayingCardPanel extends JPanel{

    private StandardDeck playingdeck;
    private PlayingCard card;

    public PlayingCardPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));   
        playingdeck = new StandardDeck();
        playingdeck.shuffle();
        playingdeck.drawTopCard();
    }

    public void drawCard(){
        playingdeck.drawTopCard();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int panelWidth = this.getWidth();
        int panelHeight = this.getHeight(); 
        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, panelWidth-1, panelHeight-1, 10, 10);
        card = playingdeck.drawTopCard();
        g.drawString(card.toString(), 75, 75);
    }
}

    package Uno;

import Uno.GameFrame;

public class GameApp{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GameFrame aBoard = new GameFrame();
        aBoard.setVisible(true);
    }

}

    package Uno;

public class PlayingCard {

    private int number; 
    private String color;

    public int getNumber() {
            return number;
    }

    public String getColor(){
            return color;
    }

    public PlayingCard(PlayingCard card){
            number = card.getNumber();
            color = new String(card.getColor());
    }   

    public PlayingCard(int cardNumber, String cardColor){
        number = cardNumber;
        color = cardColor;       
    }
}

    package Uno;

public class PlayingCard {

    private int number; 
    private String color;

    public int getNumber() {
            return number;
    }

    public String getColor(){
            return color;
    }

    public PlayingCard(PlayingCard card){
            number = card.getNumber();
            color = new String(card.getColor());
    }   

    public PlayingCard(int cardNumber, String cardColor){
        number = cardNumber;
        color = cardColor;       
    }
}

    package Uno;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class StandardDeck {

        protected Vector<PlayingCard> cardsVector;

        public StandardDeck(){     
            cardsVector = new Vector<PlayingCard>();
            String[] colors = {"blue","red","yellow","green"};
            for(String color : colors){
                for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
                        cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(i,color));
                        cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(i,color));
                }

                cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(0,color));

                for(int i=-3;i<0;i++){
                        cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(i,color));
                        cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(i,color));
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(-4,"black"));
                cardsVector.add(new PlayingCard(-5,"black"));
            }
    }

    public int getSize(){
            return cardsVector.size();
    }

    public StandardDeck reset(){
        StandardDeck resetDeck = new StandardDeck();
        return resetDeck;
    }

    public void shuffle(){
        Collections.shuffle(cardsVector);
    }

    public PlayingCard drawTopCard(){
            return new PlayingCard(cardsVector.remove(cardsVector.size()-1));
    }
}

    package Uno;

import Uno.IPlayingCard;

public interface IDeck
{
   public void reset();
   public void shuffle();
   public IPlayingCard drawTopCard(PlayingCard card);  

}


    package Uno;

import Uno.PlayingCard;

public interface IPlayingCard extends Comparable<PlayingCard>{
   public String getColor();
   public String getNumber();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to expect us to debug for you. Have you considered using a debugger to figure out for yourself what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually printing something like `Uno.PlayingCard@56609959` -- the last part of it is being truncated though, so you're only seeing "Uno" at the edge of your panel.

You are missing your `toString()` implementation in PlayingCard class.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int panelWidth = this.getWidth();
    int panelHeight = this.getHeight();
    g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, panelWidth - 1, panelHeight - 1, 10, 10);
    card = playingdeck.drawTopCard();
    g.drawString(card.toString(), 75, 75);  // you're calling toString() here...
}
```

Since you don't have it implemented, it's calling the default Object.toString() method.  You probably meant to add something like this to your PlayingCard class?

```
public String toString() {
    return ""+number;
}
```

Comment: Yep overlooked that quite a bit, only problem now is that it wont put the new card up.